# Pandas - replacing column values

Tags: python, pandas

I know there are a number of topics on this question, but none of the methods worked for me so I'm posting about my specific situation

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
data = pd.DataFrame([[1,0],[0,1],[1,0],[0,1]], columns=["sex", "split"])
data['sex'].replace(0, 'Female')
data['sex'].replace(1, 'Male')
data
```

What I want to do is replace all 0's in the sex column with 'Female', and all 1's with 'Male', but the values within the dataframe don't seem to change when I use the code above

Am I using replace() incorrectly? Or is there a better way to do conditional replacement of values?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Yes, you are using it incorrectly, [`Series.replace()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) is not inplace operation by default, it returns the replaced dataframe/series, you need to assign it back to your dataFrame/Series for its effect to occur. Or if you need to do it inplace, you need to specify the `inplace` keyword argument as `True` Example -

```
data['sex'].replace(0, 'Female',inplace=True)
data['sex'].replace(1, 'Male',inplace=True)
```

Also, you can combine the above into a single `replace` function call by using `list` for both `to_replace` argument as well as `value` argument , Example -

```
data['sex'].replace([0,1],['Female','Male'],inplace=True)
```

Example/Demo -

```
In [10]: data = pd.DataFrame([[1,0],[0,1],[1,0],[0,1]], columns=["sex", "split"])

In [11]: data['sex'].replace([0,1],['Female','Male'],inplace=True)

In [12]: data
Out[12]:
      sex  split
0    Male      0
1  Female      1
2    Male      0
3  Female      1
```

---

You can also use a dictionary, Example -

```
In [15]: data = pd.DataFrame([[1,0],[0,1],[1,0],[0,1]], columns=["sex", "split"])

In [16]: data['sex'].replace({0:'Female',1:'Male'},inplace=True)

In [17]: data
Out[17]:
      sex  split
0    Male      0
1  Female      1
2    Male      0
3  Female      1
```

Comment: Using a dictionary rather than two lists feels more natural, IMHO.

Comment: If I do something like that I get a `SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame`.

Comment: What is your code, maybe you are slicing the original dataframe as well (thereby creating a copy) and trying to set to that?

Answer (score 11):

You can also try using `apply` with `get` method of `dictionary`, seems to be little faster than `replace`:

```
data['sex'] = data['sex'].apply({1:'Male', 0:'Female'}.get)
```

Testing with `timeit`:

```
%%timeit
data['sex'].replace([0,1],['Female','Male'],inplace=True)
```

Result:

```
The slowest run took 5.83 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 510 µs per loop
```

Using `apply`:

```
%%timeit
data['sex'] = data['sex'].apply({1:'Male', 0:'Female'}.get)
```

Result:

```
The slowest run took 5.92 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 331 µs per loop
```

**Note:** `apply` with dictionary should be used if all the possible values of the columns in the dataframe are defined in the dictionary else, it will have empty for those not defined in dictionary.

Comment: What exactly does the `get` do here? Could you explain that part? The code works!

Answer (score 2):

Can try this too!
Create a dictionary of replacement values.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame([[1,0],[0,1],[1,0],[0,1]], columns=["sex", "split"])
```

[image]

```
replace_dict= {0:'Female',1:'Male'}
print(replace_dict)
```

[image]

Use the map function for replacing values

```
data['sex']=data['sex'].map(replace_dict)
```

Output after replacing
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using *Numpy*'s [`select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
import numpy as np

data['sex'] = np.select(
    [data['sex'].eq(0), data['sex'].eq(1)], ['Female', 'Male'], default=np.nan
)
```

**Output:**

```
    sex     split
0   Male    0
1   Female  1
2   Male    0
3   Female  1
```

If neither *0* or *1* is found, *NaN* is returned.

Answer (score 0):

None of these answers worked for me but this did:

```
data.gender[data['gender'] == 'Male'] = 1
data.gender[data['gender'] == 'Female'] = 2
```