# Pandas: Conditionally replace values based on other columns values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe (df) that looks like this:

```
                    environment     event   
time                    
2017-04-28 13:08:22     NaN         add_rd  
2017-04-28 08:58:40     NaN         add_rd  
2017-05-03 07:59:35     test        add_env
2017-05-03 08:05:14     prod        add_env
...
```

Now my goal is for each `add_rd` in the `event` column, the associated `NaN`-value in the `environment` column should be replaced with a string `RD`.

```
                    environment     event   
time                    
2017-04-28 13:08:22     RD          add_rd  
2017-04-28 08:58:40     RD          add_rd  
2017-05-03 07:59:35     test        add_env
2017-05-03 08:05:14     prod        add_env
...
```

---

**What I did so far**

I stumbled across `df['environment'] = df['environment].fillna('RD')` which replaces **every** `NaN` (which is not what I am looking for), `pd.isnull(df['environment'])` which is detecting missing values and `np.where(df['environment'], x,y)` which seems to be what I want but isn't working. **Furthermore did I try this**:

```
import pandas as pd

for env in df['environment']:
    if pd.isnull(env) and df['event'] == 'add_rd':
        env = 'RD'
```

The indexes are missing or some kind of iterator to access the equivalent value in the `event` column.
**And I tried this**:

```
df['environment'] = np.where(pd.isnull(df['environment']), df['environment'] = 'RD', df['environment'])

SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

which obviously didn't worked.

I took a look at several questions but couldn't build on the suggestions in the answers. [Black's question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23307361/10099689) [Simon's question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31888920/10099689) [szli's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas) [Jan Willems Tulp's question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10726275/10099689)

So, how do I replace a value in a column based on another columns values?

Comment: Use `df.loc[df['environment'].isnull() & df['event'].eq('add_rd'), 'environment'] = 'RD'`

Comment: Your last attempt is very close - I think you just need to change it to `df['environment'] = np.where(pd.isnull(df['environment']), 'RD', df['environment'])`

Comment: @asongtoruin I am officially blind ;) ... that worked!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Now my goal is for each add_rd in the event column, the associated
>   NaN-value in the environment column should be replaced with a string
>   RD.

As per @Zero's comment, use [`pd.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and Boolean indexing:

```
df.loc[df['event'].eq('add_rd') & df['environment'].isnull(), 'environment'] = 'RD'
```

Answer (score 5):

You could consider using [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
df.environment.where((~df.environment.isnull()) & (df.event != 'add_rd'),
                     'RD', inplace=True)
```

If the condition is not met, the values is replaced by the second element.

Answer (score 2):

Replace values in specific column using DataFrame.loc

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: dictionary = {'time': ['2017-04-28 13:08:22', '2017-04-28 08:58:40', 
                               '2017-05-03 07:59:35','2017-05-03 08:05:14'],
                       'environment': ['NaN', 'NaN', 'test', 'prod'], 
                       'event': ['add_rd', 'add_rd', 'add_env', 'add_env']
                     }

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary, columns= ['time', 'environment', 'event'])
        print(df) 
        
Out [3]:                  time environment    event
         0  2017-04-28 13:08:22         NaN   add_rd
         1  2017-04-28 08:58:40         NaN   add_rd
         2  2017-05-03 07:59:35        test  add_env
         3  2017-05-03 08:05:14        prod  add_env

In [4]: df.loc[df['event'] == 'add_rd', 'environment'] = 'RD'
        print(df) 
        
Out [4]:                  time environment    event
         0  2017-04-28 13:08:22          RD   add_rd
         1  2017-04-28 08:58:40          RD   add_rd
         2  2017-05-03 07:59:35        test  add_env
         3  2017-05-03 08:05:14        prod  add_env
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to replace just 'add_rd' with 'RD', this can be useful to you

```
keys_to_replace = {'add_rd':'RD','add_env':'simple'}
df['environment'] = df.groupby(['event'])['environment'].fillna(keys_to_replace['add_rd'])
df
```

output:

```
    environment event
0   RD          add_rd
1   RD          add_rd
2   test        add_env
3   prod        add_env
```

if you have many values to replace based on event, then you may need to follow groupby with 'event' column values

```
keys_to_replace = {'add_rd':'RD','add_env':'simple'}
temp = df.groupby(['event']).apply(lambda x:  x['environment'].fillna(keys_to_replace[x['event'].values[0]]))
temp.index = temp.index.droplevel(0)
df['environment'] = temp.sort_index().values
```

output:

```
   environment  event
0   RD          add_rd
1   RD          add_rd
2   test        add_env
3   prod        add_env
```

Comment: No need for all this. I know the question  has already been answered but  this could have been done with a simple fillna

Answer (score -1):

Here it is:

```
 df['environment']=df['environment'].fillna('RD')
```

Comment: "I stumbled across df['environment'] = df['environment].fillna('RD') which replaces every NaN (which is not what I am looking for),"

Thanks for your contribution, but read the question pls. I already found this one