# Assigning a value to a DataFrame column based on the value of a random variable

Tags: python, dataframe, conditional-statements, assign

I have a DataFrame like this:

```py
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['count', 'color'])
```

For each row that has count > 0, I want to assign 'red' to color if

```py
    np.random.binomial(1,prob)==1
```

I know how to do it with a for loop.
I also know that, if there wasn't this condition, I could assign the red color without a for loop, in this way:

```py
    df.loc[df['count']>0, ['color']]='red'
```

Is it possible to have both the filter on count and the condition on prob without the for loop?

Comment: Using a single trial in the binomial distribution doesn't make sense. You should just use a boolean for counts>0.

Comment: My intention is to assign color to red with a given prob only to rows with a count > 0. In the for loop, I run a trial for each of the rows  with count > 0, and it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
df.loc[lambda x: (x['count'] > 0) & (np.random.binomial(1, prob)==1), 'color'] = 'red'
```

[pandas.DataFrame.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

[Pandas: Conditionally replace values based on other columns values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52224142/pandas-conditionally-replace-values-based-on-other-columns-values#52225027)

Comment: It seems to me that the random condition is evaluated only once for all the rows with count > 0. I need to have it evaluated separately for every row matching the count condition

Comment: I have updated the code to use lambda function. Does this work for you?

Comment: Yes it does! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
reds = np.where(d['counts']>1)[0]            # indices of red elements
probs = np.random.binomial(1,0.2, len(reds)) # probs to be assigned to red elements

# assign
d.loc[reds, "color"] = ['red' if i==1 else 'blue' for i in probs]
```

I am assuming data like the one generated here.

```
a = np.random.randint(0,10,100)
b = ['blue']*100
d = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([a,b]).T, columns=['counts','color'])
d.loc[:,'counts'] = d.loc[:,'counts'].astype(int)
```